# Laptop battery charging/not charging eratically

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery

I noticed today that my HP DV6 6008eg laptop running Windows 10 eratically reports that the battery is charging and not charging. The small LED near the AC plug also changes its colour accordingly with the Windows battery status. 
However, if my laptop is closed or in stand-by mode, then the status (according to the LED) is proper and stays consistent.

Any ideas what software issues might cause such behaviour?

Comment: I don't think this is a software issue. I did have a similar issue with my phone's charging. Try using a different AC power cord as that turned out to be the issue on my phone. I recommend not charging when this happens, as in my case, the charger started smoking